# How to use foreach to extract from mysql?

Tags: php

i have problems with my script.
Table looks like this:
Tara: Romania, US, Canada, Apple
Rank: 11,12,13,14

```
$tari = array("Romania", "Ukraina", "Danemarca", "Rusia", "Norvegia", 
   "Serbia", "Slovenia", "Irlanda", "Lituania", "Estonia", "Croatia", "Austria",
   "Belarus", "Moldova", "Belgia");

foreach ($tari as $tara)
{
    $query4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$tara`");
    $row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query4);
    $name = $row4['Tara'];
    $rank = $row4['Voturi'];
    echo $name;
    echo $rank;
}
```

Result should be:

```
Romania 11
US 12
Canada 13
Apple 14
```

but appear

```
Romania 11
Romania 11
Romania 11
Romania 11
```

What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: could you provide more details about your table schemata? I am bit confused here what the structure actually looks like

Comment: yes shure right here...http://pastebin.com/4gzimmVz

Comment: Why do you have it duplicated for the every country?

Comment: i make 15 tables with same content because if you are from romania and want to vote "canada" you need to do that in Romania table on Canade field. I try to make eurovision system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to make all these tables into **one**
2. Then you'll have to select required rows using usual WHERE condition
3. Or, if you need all of them - without condition at all

   ```
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM romania");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
       echo $row['Tara'];
       echo $row['Voturi'];
   }
   ```

#### that's the only right way

Ok, now we have the case:

> if you are from romania and want to vote "canada" you need to do that in Romania table on Canade field. I try to make eurovision system

you need [at least] 2 tables:

- `tari` with countries
- `voturi` with votes

`tari` table have to be at least of 2 fields: `id` and `name`
`votury` table have to be at least of 2 fields: `from` and `for`

So, if Romania have id 1 and Canada 15 and someone from Romania wants to vote for Canada, add a row into `voturi` table:

```
1, 15
```

and later you'll be able to count any statistics from it. Say, if you want to see, how many Canadians voted for Romania,

```
SELECT count(1) FROM voturi WHERE `from`=15 and `for`=1;
```

to get Romanian votes for all countries

```
SELECT `for`, count(1) FROM voturi WHERE `from` = 1 GROUP BY `for`;
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in line 108 witch is  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

Comment: ok it's working,but now i need to sort DESC votes and the highest one shoud recieve 12 points second one 10 third one 8 , the one situated on the fourth place 7 and so on up to the last place that should recieve only 1 point.These values must be added into a new table : [for, from, 12/8..etc points]